# Generating User-Friendly URLs, with simplicity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, seo

So, the deal is, i have this function at a CMS:

```
function generateDocumentUrl($docid) {
    global $glob, $db, $config;     

    $query = "SELECT doc_name FROM ".$glob['dbprefix']."CubeCart_docs WHERE doc_id='".$docid."'"; 
    $sef_documents = $db->select($query);

    $sefpre = ($config['sefserverconfig'] == 0 || $config['sefserverconfig'] == 3) ? 'info_' : 'i_';
    $ext = ($config['sefserverconfig'] == 3) ? '.php' : '.html';

    $doc = $sef_documents[0]['doc_name'];
    if (strlen($doc) > 0) {
        $doc = generateSafeUrls($doc);
        $doc = $doc . "/";
    }
    $doc = $doc . $sefpre . $docid;

    return strtolower($doc);
}
```

The generated URLS are like:

www.website.com/contacts/info_12

```
    $doc = $doc . $sefpre . $docid;
```

This generates the output, i can manage to put it like:

www.website.com/contacts/12

But what i really need is

www.website.com/contacts

I tried to play with the function but can't really achieve the final result :(

Comment: As an aside, be sure to escape your queries with `mysql_real_escape_string` - for example, `SELECT doc_name FROM " . mysql_real_escape_string($glob['dbprefix'] . "`

Comment: Second aside - your function is open to a SQL injection attack. Consider PDO or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the $sefpre . $docid is what is after the final / based on that code. Removing that would remove your trailing directory.

Doing that however may cause problems: from the code sample above, we cannot see what is converting these virtual directories into output (ex. htaccess file + some function in your cms looking up the url aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about this suggests simplicity. It looks like a pointlessly convoluted way to handle something that is easy to achieve using htaccess or even a basic URI parsing class in php.

Perhaps you should revise your question with specifics about which CMS you're using.